# IIS 7 URL Rewrite for HTTPS

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I want to redirect https://example.com to https://www.example.com. I have the following rule for redirecting non www http traffic to https://www . . .

```
<rule name="WWW Redirect1" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^example\.com$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

This will not handle redirecting from https://example.com to https://www.examlple. Right now I currently get the SSL cert error, is it even possible to avoid this?

Comment: The URL Rewrite module kicks in only after SSL connection is established. If you see an SSL warning when accessing `example.com`, then your certificate does not cover that domain name (as I understand it covers only subdomains `*.example.com`). Therefore you cannot redirect just like that -- you need to "fix" your certificate somehow (contact issuer about including `example.com` as well into a certificate). The only other way is to have another cert for `example.com` which has to be bound to another IP (IIS does not support more than one SSL certificate per IP:port combination).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are getting an SSL certificate error, it likely means that either

1. Your web server is not serving up an SSL certificate for `https://www.example.com` or;
2. Your SSL certificate is for `example.com` not `www.example.com`. In which case, you'll likely need to address that with your SSL certificate provider.

Not sure that it is an issue with code or config....

Comment: The SSL error shows up for https://example.com because the cert is good for *.example.com but it will work fine for www.example.com.